# APPDATA is not returned in Python executed via CGI

Tags: python, apache, cgi, nltk, appdata

I'm using Python with the NLTK toolkit in Apache via CGI. The toolkit need to know the APPDATA directory, but when executed in the server, the `os.environ` not lists the`APPDATA`.

When I execute a simple `print os.envrion` in console, `APPDATA` is present, but not when executed via CGI in the web server.

What is going on? How can I solve this? I'm new to Python and I'm just learning it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is quite possible. The CGI environment is different from the environment in the console.

You can set the variable from Apache (from `apache.conf`):

```
SetEnv APPDATA 1.2.3.4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

`%APPDATA%` is a special variable that expands to the "Application Data" directory of the user who expands the variable (i.e., who runs a script). Apache is not running as you, so it has no business knowing about *your* APPDATA directory.

You should either hard-code the relevant path into your script, or replace it with a path relative to the location of the script, e.g., `r'..\data\nltk_data'`. If you really need to, you can recover the absolute location of your script by looking at `__file__`.

Answer (score 1):

The module check this before running:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32' and 'APPDATA' in os.environ
```

But APPDATA doesn't exist in Apache because it's running as another user different from yours.

so you have to assign your APPDATA manually

```
import os
os.environ.__setitem__('APPDATA','C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages')
```

For my case, i use python 2.7, and I store all the packages in site-packages, so they are accessible for all users. so i don't really need to give my user appdata folder.