# "import nltk" - Not working on xampp

Tags: apache, python-2.7, cgi, nltk

I'm new to python and nltk. I have problem on import nltk.
I installed python in xampp on windows under the path C:\xampp\Python.
And I installed nltk under the path C:\xampp\Python.
After this I configured apache and run some sample python code, it worked well on the browser.
The URL  is :  /localhost/cgi-bin/test.py.
When I import the nltk in test.py its not running. The execution not continue after the "import nltk" line.
But when I run in the command prompt its working perfect.
Please let me know how to fix this issue. 
Below is the sample code :

```
#!C:\Xampp\Python\python  
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"  
import nltk  
print "<html>"  
print "<head>"  
print "<title>This is test</title>"  
print "</head>"  
print "<body>"  
print "This is paragraph"  
print "</body>"  
print "</html>"
```

I checked in the apache error log it look like below.
[Fri May 17 18:21:28.774308 2013] [cgi:error] [pid 2952:tid 1732] [client] AH01215: ValueError: Could not find a default download directory\r

I'm creating UI for nltk please help me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the code [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.downloader-pysrc.html), it appears that the library has platform-specific path handling and that error is thrown in the *nix branch. The code to detect Windows looks like this:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32' and 'APPDATA' in os.environ
```

I hope that `sys.platform` isn't getting messed up, so I think it's most likely that Apache isn't propagating the `APPDATA` environment variable down to your code.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219319/appdata-is-not-returned-in-python-executed-via-cgi) explains why that is and gives a workaround.